# Match using [] - Only first part X number of times (using {})

Tags: regex

Sorry for the poor title, but this is  quite hard to summarize.

So, let's assume I have the following data:

```
123
1 2 3
12 3
1  2  3
1  23
```

The `1`, `2` and `3` can be replaced by any digit (`\d`)

I need to match all of those using just a RegEx, I want to know if it is possible (this is a hypothetical situation by the way, so no need to worry about language or why I will require this).

To match the first case, `123`, I can use this RegEx: `\d{3}`. Now if I wanted to include matching spaces, and the whole thing be 3 digits / letters long, I could use `[\d\s]{3}`. However, this will match the first case, but for it to match the second I must change it to `[\d\s]{5}`.

What I want is to be able to select the number of times to repeat (in this case, `{3}`), however let there be any amount of spaces in between the numbers.

I could use `\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*`, but that is very inefficient. Using `[\d\s*]{3}` does not work either, the same reason as above.

Maybe it is possible using capture groups, hopefully you can see what I am trying to get at:

```
[(\d)\s*]$1{3}
```

Comment: You should note, that `*` loses it's metacharacter function inside a character class and is just matched literally, so `[\d\s*]` matches either 1 space or 1 digit or 1 `*`

Comment: @SebastianProske Yes, I know, it was just showing what I was trying to achieve. I'll edit and put `()` now, thanks!

Comment: your edit made things just worse - brackets have no metacharacter function inside chracter classes. Only `-` works as range and `^` works as negation (if put at the start)

Comment: @SebastianProske Thanks, I did not realize that. I'll undo it.

Comment: What you might wanted to show is `(\d\s*)\1{2}` - capturing `\d\s*` and then repeating twice (which won't work, as the backreference is matching the match again, not the pattern)

Comment: @SebastianProske What does the `\1` do normally, out of interest? Get the value of the first capturing group?

Comment: It's a backreference to the first captured group, matching it's content again.

Comment: @SebastianProske I thought so, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex

**Regex:** `(?:\d\s*){3}`

**Explanation:**

- `(?:\d\s*)` will match any `digit` followed by `zero` or more spaces, which will be repeated 3 times by using `{3}`.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH6lM5/2)**</kbd>

**P.S:** You were close to solution. You should had used capturing groups `()` instead of character class `[]`.

What character class does is **select** one out of mentioned characters.

Comment: You can skip the capturing part and just get the grouping with `(?:\d\s*){3}`

Comment: @Alec: Yes we can but we are not running out of backreferences here. Anyways thanks for advice.

Comment: It will probably be _slightly_ faster to not capture, although you most likely won't notice the difference in normal use

Comment: @Alec: If you say so. Done !

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of that!